# Wolfram Workbench and Mathematica Help System

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I find the [Wolfram Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/) a nice environment for Mathematica development.

However, as I program in Mathematica, I need to navigate the Help System very often.

The Workbench provides a tooltip tool that shows a very basic help for the Mma functions (just the usage messages), and is not enough for my usual needs.

So: Is there a way to bring up and navigate the whole Mma Help System from inside the Workbench?

Alternative solutions are also welcome. Re-entering the function name in a notebook and pressing F1 is not :)

Comment: Is this on topic? Doesn't seem very much programming related. More like needing help with an application.

Comment: @IAbstract Programming environments are on-topic AFAIK. The Workbench is in fact an Eclipse incarnation.

Comment: @IAbstract Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797806/what-tricks-can-be-used-to-type-and-edit-code-faster/2798097#2798097 :)

Comment: That was CW - and I remember adding to the post. That same question *might* not be allowed on SO today but has been kept as a very useful archive, in my opinion. But that is why we have the community to make decisions.

Comment: I think "How do I get more comprehensive function help in my IDE?" is a valid SO question.

Comment: @IAbstract No problem. Vote to close or migrate if you think it's more on-topic on other site. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a valid question for mathematica tag until the separate stackexchange takes off (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15787/mathematica)

Comment: @Yaroslav: I can agree with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/helplookup.html)

By highlighting the function and pressing `Ctrl+Shift+/` a Web Browser pops up and shows the appropriate Wolfram's help page on the Internet.

The question is still alive, as it should be better to show up the *local* Help System.

Comment: I'm accepting my answer temporarily, until someone comes up with a way to use the **local** help files. Tip Window->Preferences->Mathematica->Editor->Help ... and something should be patched there.

Comment: So did you come up with a solution? I am finding myself using Eclipse more and more as I switch between Python and mma constantly, and looking up the docs easily would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been re-installing Workbench 2.0 on Mint Mfce 17.1 and have run into this problem.

Do you have a browser set for viewing help?

Wolfram Workbench, menu:Windows|Preferences, tree:General|Web Browser

I've got mine set to the output of "which firefox".  Sadly, I cannot get this mechanism to honor -new-window as an option (nor -no-remote), so the contents from 127.0.0.1 always show up in some other already open Firefox window.  Meh.  Note that you need not list the %URL% as a parameter (unless one of the parameters you give *also* requires it); it will be appended to whatever you supply.